# Mercurial status not showing modified files

Tags: mercurial

I'm running Mercurial 1.6.4 on my Debian server. It is not showing modified files that I know have been modified.

I'll modify a file, and an `hg status` will show:

```
! filename.txt
```

Then I run an `hg status` again and nothing shows up. I've tried to check in a file I know was modified, and alas, Mercurial says nothing was changed.

I even ran a `hg st --all | grep 'M '` and it shows the modified files! Yet I can't check them in.

Comment: ! means deleted, not modified.

Comment: Are you saying that if you run `hg status` twice, the first time it'll show your file as deleted, and the second time it won't show it at all?

Comment: What does your .hgignore contain?

Comment: To Lasse, yes, that is what I'm saying.

Comment: To OJ - just to ignore a single file. It's something to do with that server, I believe, because Mercurial works just fine on my local Linux machine. I guess I'll just reinstall it.

Answer (score 2):

You should double-check that the [inotify extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/InotifyExtension) has not been enabled without your knowledge. Some older Debian packaged enabled it by default in the system-wide config. Use

```
hg showconfig --debug extensions
```

to list the enabled extensions and to list where each setting is read from. If it is enabled, you can disable it by adding

```
[extensions]
inotify = !
```

to your `~/.hgrc` file or by editing the global config file.

Answer (score -1):

> I've tried to check in a file I know
>   was modified, and alas, Mercurial says
>   nothing was changed.

If you 'check it in', ie: commit, then status will not show it as modified because it has not been modified since the last commit.

Comment: S/he **tried** to check it in, but Hg wouldn't do it, because it claims nothing has changed. Your answer unfortunately makes an assumption that's unjustified by the wording of the question.